# Retrieve 3600 messages in single pubNub ajax request

Tags: pubnub

The PubNub History API states that

```
The history() function returns a list of up to 100 messages, the start time token and the ending time token.
```

Is there a way to retrieve 3600 messages in a single pubNub ajax request?
Currently i am getting the 3600 messages in 36 ajax request.
Please help me to improve the performance...

Comment: What is your use-case for needed more than 100 at-a-time ?

Comment: I have used highstock chart for showing the stock history.For showing one hour of data in chart,it requires 3600 messages.(It takes 36 ajax pubnub request to get the 3600 history of messages).It takes 12 seconds to get the 3600 messages

Comment: How big is each message in bytes?

Comment: Its not about size... We need to reduce the ajax request...

Comment: Well, one idea is the concept of putting more data into a single message, and doing history only off that "compressed channel" (batch publish 100 msgs into a history channel, so each history response will yield 100*100) But if that won't work, please contact us at support@pubnub.com and we can dig deeper with you.

Comment: Do u have any reference for batch publishing to get 100 * 100 messages?

Comment: please contact us at support@pubnub.com to assist you further with this...

Comment: Vinoth, just following up to see if support was able to assist you.